# What is the best jquery selector for making this change?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following html where I use the jquery **after** method() to stick in some new HTML.  This works fine but I now have a situation where I don't want it to apply the after() method under certain conditions (where an additional class exists in a top TD) and i am trying to figure out the correct jquery selector syntax.

To make this more concrete, to start, I have the following html:

```
 <td class="fc-widget-content">
 <div>
      <div class="fc-day-number">1</div>
      <div class="fc-day-content">
  </div>
  </td>
```

and I want the following logic:  I want to stick this html:

```
      <span class="addEventHidden" style="display: none;">
            <img src="/Content/Images/addEvent.gif">
      </span>
```

right after the **fc-day-number** div.  I can do this easily by doing this:

```
$('.fc-day-number').after(function () {
    return "<span class='addEventHidden' style='display: none;'><img src='/Content/Images/addEvent.gif'></span>";
});
```

this works great except in some cases I don't want to run the .after() method if the top div has this extra class:  **fc-other-month**

so apply this after command if the top looks like this:

```
 <td class="fc-widget-content">
```

but NOT if the top TD looks like this:

```
 <td class="fc-widget-content fc-other-month">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$('td.fc-widget-content:not(.fc-other-month) div.fc-day-number')
    .after('<span class="addEventHidden" ... >');
```

Example has line break for clarity. Replace `<span class="addEventHidden" ... >` with legit html.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.fc-widget-content .fc-day-number').not('.fc-other-month .fc-day-number').after(function () {
    return "<span class='addEventHidden' style='display: none;'><img src='/Content/Imags/addEvent.gif'></span>";
});
```

Comment: `fc-other-month` is the parent's class.

Comment: fc-other-month is not going to be a class at the same level as the fc-day-number, its a class of the TD above it . . i assume some syntax needs to account for that

Answer (score -2):

```
$(".fc-widget-content:not(.fc-other-month):parent(.fc-day-number) .fc-day-number");
```

Comment: This will target the `td`, not the `div`.

Comment: [`:parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/) doesn't work that way.  I think you mean `:parent` or `:has(.fc-day-number)`.  Either way, those aren't needed, you can just do `".fc-widget-content:not(.fc-other-month) .fc-day-number`.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `.filter` to only get `divs`s with the correct parent:

```
$('.fc-day-number').filter(function(){
    return $(this).closest('.fc-other-month').length === 0;
}).after(function () {
    return "<span class='addEventHidden' style='display: none;'><img src='/Content/Images/addEvent.gif'></span>";
});
```

Or you can use a more specific selector to select the `div`.

```
$('.fc-widget-content:not(.fc-other-month) .fc-day-number').after(function () {
    return "<span class='addEventHidden' style='display: none;'><img src='/Content/Images/addEvent.gif'></span>";
});
```

P.S. You forgot a `</div>` before your `</td>`.

Comment: I did not vote, but checking for the "correct parent" seems like an awkward way to do it. Your second solution has mismatched double/single quotes in the selector.

Comment: @Mathletics: The 1st was just a suggestion, never said it was the best idea.  Also, fixed the quotes. :-P